# Chrome driver value gets null after extends to other class

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have test class "Test" and a configuration class "Base", in the configuration class I set the driver instance it has been extends to test class "Test"

The value of driver get null for chrome driver but getting value for firefox driver 
in the test class "Test"

Chrome driver set up:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\Eclipse workspace_POC\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");       
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

Firefox driver set up:

```
WebDriver driver = new firefoxDriver();
```

can anyone sort the issue.

Comment: Neither of those two calls can return null, if actually executed. Can you clarify where you're calling them (different classes, different methods?) and by posting some actual code?

Comment: in different classs i am calling

Comment: Can you share error-log and source code?

Answer (score 0):

Try using Static Instances.. Something like,

```
// In Test Class 
public static WebDriver driver = null; 

// Config Class [Works only if u extend Test. If not try Test.driver] 
driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

Comment: Introducing a static (and widening the scope) will only compound the OP's problem of not understanding how inheritance works.

Comment: You are right, however the other option is to make the driver "Final" and access the driver in child class using a helper class. This will only complicate things more !! So, static driver implementation may be fine as long as u understand the implications